# elevateZoom not working since upgrading from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1

Tags: product, ce-1.9.1.0, zoom, elevate

Just upgraded from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 and now the product zoom is not working.  It sort of works on some products but way of its focus. So not sure what has happened would really appreciate any advice.  This is a great feature of magento and enhances the shopping experience. 
Many thanks
jagall

Answer (score 1):

Try have a look on this file: **(/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js)** and look for `image.elevateZoom();`and check if it is commented, if so, delete the comments and run it again.